# Magnific popup target to iframe parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, magnific-popup

I have a web-page with some small iframes, When user click on a button in iframe - shows big form with `type: inline`. How would I get the popup to open in the parent page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**
In latest versions - even easier.
Author add param `prependTo`

```
 var conf = {type: 'inline', preloader: false};
 if (window.location != window.parent.location) {
     conf.prependTo = window.parent.$('body');
 }
```

Done. Little, ugly hack
Add new option - target

```
var conf = {type: 'inline', preloader: false};
if (window.location != window.parent.location) {
    conf.target = $(window.parent.window);
}
```

And in source, in function `addGroup`

```
if (typeof options.target != 'undefined') {
    _window = options.target;
} else {
    _window = $(window);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are owner of child iframe than you can add clickHandler that will trigger some custom in parent. Please take a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement)

eg. `parent.$('body').trigger('custom:event');`